# wire and wireless suddenly disappeared

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ethernet

My laptop has Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS . Wire and wireless suddenly not accessible. Clicking top right on my desktop either wire or wireless icons disappeared. Clicking setting>Network there is absolutely nothing.
typing on the terminal **lshw -c network** ,

- the terminal responds that the network is unclaimed,
- ethernet controller and network controller appear.
- the following warning message at the bottom: " output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super -user"

I did type on the terminal: **lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280**
the result is

- 01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]:Realtek Semiconductor Co. , Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
- 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)

I type on the terminal: **sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status** the result is

- install reinstreq half-installed

I rebooted to an earlier kernel version

[image]

If I choose the version 6.2.0-36 , the wireless is back

Also I have the following **invalid config** message when rebooting
[image]

If I choose the version 6.2.0-35 , the wireless works and the error message is no longer there;but, the computer freeze , browser close by itself, and log off...

---

**After booting with -36  and typing the command sudo apt update**

**and typing the command sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic**

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> The following additional packages will be installed:
> linux-modules-6.2.0-37-generic
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
> linux-modules-6.2.0-37-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic
> 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
> Need to get 0 B/99.2 MB of archives.
> After this operation, 575 MB of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
> Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-6.2.0-37-generic.
> (Reading database ... 282087 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-6.2.0-37-generic_6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1_amd64
> .deb ...
> Unpacking linux-modules-6.2.0-37-generic (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1) ...
> Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic.
> Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic_6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1
> _amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1) ...
> Setting up linux-modules-6.2.0-37-generic (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1) ...

> Setting up linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1) ...###############....................................................…

**After typing the command: sudo dmesg | grep gpio**

> [    1.488055] amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014

**after sudo apt update > sudo apt upgrade > sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic , terminal message is different:**

> sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic
> [sudo] password for nay:
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
> libwmf0.2-7 linux-headers-6.2.0-35-generic linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-35
> linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-35-generic
> linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-35-generic
> Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
> Need to get 0 B/74.1 MB of archives.
> After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
> (Reading database ... 318986 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic_6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1) over (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1) ...
> Setting up linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1) ...
> Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1) ...
> /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
> update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-37-generic
> /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
> Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub' Sourcing file` /etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
> Generating grub configuration file ...
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-37-generic
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-37-generic
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-36-generic
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-35-generic
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-35-generic
> Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
> Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
> Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
> Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
> Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
> done

**sudo dmesg | grep gpio**

> 1.475704] amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014

After restarting normally the computer there is still the same invalid message appearing during booting

Internet Works, and after typing **uname -r**

> 6.2.0-37-generic

Internet Problem solved! Thx to Mr. Chili555

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280` and also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` Can you reboot into an earlier kernel version at the GRUB menu and are both working there?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time

Comment: While booted into -36 and doing nothing, can you open a terminal? If so, do: `sudo apt update` and: `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic` Also, let us see: `sudo dmesg | grep gpio`